# Why String.() -> Unit is the same as (String) -> Unit in my code?

Tags: function, kotlin, types, kotlin-function-type

I am struggling to understand how a function type with receiver works in Kotlin. I don't understand why we can use (String) -> Unit and String.() -> Unit in my code indistinctively

```
fun main() {
    var showStringFunction1: (String) -> Unit = ::showString
    showStringFunction1("Hey")
    var showStringFunction2: String.() -> Unit = ::showString
    showStringFunction2("Hey")
}

fun showString(x: String): Unit { println(x) }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between these only matters when either:

1. You are passing a lambda. It affects whether the first parameter is `this` or a named parameter inside the lambda. If you pass something other than a lambda, the receiver can be thought of as the first function argument.
2. You are invoking it. The receiver version is more versatile because you can *also* choose to invoke it like an extension function. But you can also invoke it as if the receiver is the first function argument.

A related concept comes when passing a function argument. So, `showString` could be an extension `fun String.showString(): Unit` and it could be passed to either of your variables in the example.

Comment: In fact, I'd go further and say that you _should_ invoke the receiver version like an extension function; the example should read `"Hey".showStringFunction2()` instead of `showStringFunction2("Hey")`.  AIUI, the fact that the latter works at all is merely an artefact of how functions with receiver are implemented by the compiler, and for Java interoperability.

Comment: Yes, giving it a receiver type indicates that is the preferred usage.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to reason about it the other way around:
`String.() -> Unit` would be translated by Kotlin compiler to `(String) -> Unit`, hence they are the same.

Using "Show Kotlin Bytecode"/"Decompile" you'll get the following result from both cases:

```
public final class AKt/BKt {
   private static final void showString(String x) {
      boolean var1 = false;
      System.out.println(x);
   }

   public static final void main() {
      Function1 showStringFunction2 = (Function1)null.INSTANCE;
      showStringFunction2.invoke("Hey");
   }

   // $FF: synthetic method
   public static void main(String[] var0) {
      main();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the `(String) -> Unit` and `String.() -> Unit` are mapped to same JVM signature i.e. implementation of interface `KFunciton1<String, Unit>`. That's why they behave the same.

The only difference you'll find is that when you are creating these you'll be presented with `this` in case of `String.() -> Unit` while any variable as of your choice in `(String) -> Unit`.

While in case of referencing it is the same. However in Kotlin-1.4 I heard they are separating them (don't know if its true, will update answer if I confirm it).